# Google docs API: Update several cells at same time

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-api, google-docs-api

I use Google docs API in php with Zend GData. With this library, I can update spreadsheet cell one by one like this:

```
$googleDocs->updateCell(
    1, 1, 'test', $this->spreadsheetKey, $this->worksheetKey
);
```

But, to optimize my application, I would like to send several cells at same time but I don't find how to do this.

Comment: Your question is nearly two years old. How did you solve your problem? Did you found an answer to this? Maybe in a newer version of the API? Or did you just screwed it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want update several cells from the same row, you can use the function `updateRow`.

If you want update a column I did not figured out a way to do that.